# Can a Parcelable contain an AIDL Interface?

Tags: android, parcelable, aidl

I have a Service that communicates via AIDL.  I have successfully created a callback interface and use a class that implements Parcelable.

I want to have the Parcelable contain a reference to the Interface defined in the AIDL file but I get the error that my callback class can't be converted to Parcelable. "incompatible types: ICallback cannot be converted to Parcelable"

My Parcelable looks like this

```
class Foo implements Parcelable {
   String someString;
   ICallback callback;
....
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(someString);
        dest.writeParcelable(callback, flags); //doesn't work
    }

}
```

The AIDL for the service has a method like:

```
void register(Foo[] someFoos);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that your `ICallback` is a Binder interface, so you have a declaration of the form `interface ICallback { ... }` in some AIDL file.

In this case, you can write it to a `Parcel` using `parcel.writeStrongBinder(callback.asBinder())` or with the convenience method `parcel.writeStrongInterface(callback);`. On the receiving end, it can be retrieved with:

`callback = ICallback.Stub.asInterface(parcel.readStrongBinder());`

API Reference:

- [writeStrongInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeStrongInterface(android.os.IInterface))
- [writeStrongBinder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeStrongBinder(android.os.IBinder))
- [readStrongBinder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readStrongBinder())

Examples from Android Framework:

- `InputBindResult`:  [writeStrongInterface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/c185f08c4a408fa7abc578851d31cdce6ad86f6f/core/java/com/android/internal/view/InputBindResult.java#220) / [readStrongBinder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/c185f08c4a408fa7abc578851d31cdce6ad86f6f/core/java/com/android/internal/view/InputBindResult.java#192)
- `ParcelableCall`: [writeStrongBinder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/61460ac068b0a1a97d9add423396857716951922/telecomm/java/android/telecom/ParcelableCall.java#417) / 
  [readStrongBinder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/61460ac068b0a1a97d9add423396857716951922/telecomm/java/android/telecom/ParcelableCall.java#343)